# Pyodbc invalid parameter type

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pyodbc

I am running into this problem

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=type', 'HY105')     
[SQL: SELECT TOP 1 votes.user_id AS votes_user_id, votes.post_id AS votes_post_id
FROM votes
WHERE votes.post_id = ? AND votes.user_id = ?]
[parameters: (<class 'int'>, 18)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I guess the error happened in this line

```
vote_query = db.query(models.Vote).filter(models.Vote.post_id == vote.post_id,
                                            models.Vote.user_id == current_user.id)
```

But I can not fix this.

All related code I am posting below

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Response, status, Depends, APIRouter
from .. import schemas, database, models, oauth2
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/vote", 
    tags=["Vote"]
)

@router.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def vote(vote: schemas.Vote, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db), current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):

    vote_query = db.query(models.Vote).filter(models.Vote.post_id == vote.post_id,
                                            models.Vote.user_id == current_user.id)
    found_vote = vote_query.first()
    
    # user wants to add a new vote
    if vote.dir == 1:
        if found_vote:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail=f"user {current_user.id} has already voted on post {vote.post_id}")
        
        new_vote = models.Vote(post_id = vote.post_id, user_id = current_user.id)
        db.add(new_vote)
        db.commit()
        return {
            "message": "Successfully added vote"
        }

    # user wants to delete an existed vote
    else:
        if not found_vote:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="vote does not exist")

        vote_query.delete(synchronize_session=False)
        db.commit()

        return {
            "message": "successfully deleted vote"
        }
```

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(VARCHAR(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(VARCHAR(50), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('Getdate()'), nullable=False)


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(NVARCHAR(50), nullable=False)
    content = Column(NVARCHAR(100), nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default=text('1'), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('Getdate()'), nullable=False)

    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)

    owner = relationship("User")
class Vote(Base):
    __tablename__ = "votes"

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id"), primary_key=True)
```

```
class Vote(BaseModel):
    post_id = int
    dir = conint(le=1)
```

I am using Postman to send request

```
{
    "post_id": 4,
    "dir": 1
}
```

Comment: You're _assigning_ the types as the default values to your request, you're not defining them as types (use `:` instead of `=` to define a type for the field - the error message is saying that "we got the int class, not an int value as a parameter": `post_id = int` should be `post_id: int` (and the same change for `dir`).

Comment: Where is that? Can you write the code in your comment?